# How about adding font embedding for pronunciations characters?

Tags: feature-request, pronunciation

[image]

How about adding font embedding for pronunciations characters like the one does at math.SE site?

[image]

I don't mean to add MathJax to here, only embedding a font will work for this english.SE site.

Comment: You mean to add the character support in order to avoid seeing boxes?

Comment: @Alenanno, yeah

Answer (score 6):

Yes, an open-source Unicode IPA font would be great to have included on the site, as a fallback font for characters that can't be displayed in the browser's main font.